# Page Layout Content Types vs. Publishing Content Types

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, content-type, page-layout

I begun to create layout pages for a group of sites and am struggling to understand out of the box usage. I created two layouts; one for Publishing Content Types and another for Page Layout Content Types.  They work fine, but if I begin to create a web part page within the browser I don't see an option for the layout I created.  If I choose a Publishing page, I do see both options.  Am I being confused by semantics here? One is Page Layout and the other is simply Layout.

With that in mind, how may I create web part page layouts that I can choose within the browser?  Additionally, if Publishing is turned off for a given site collection, may I still provide my clients custom templates for web part pages (even wiki pages) or do I need to create custom content types from scratch?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here are my 5 cents.

Page Layouts - think of them as a html layout/design of the page. It can contain webpart zones, html elements, etc.

Page Content Type - properties of the Page Layout.

For example: You design a page to fit your look/branding. But at the same time you want that page layout to have extra properties. Imagine you have an Article page layout, but you want to have a department property associated to that page layout. You create a content type with a column of type drop-down and then associate this content type to your page layout.

So anytime now you use your Article Page layout, this extra property will be available for you to use.

Comment: Much appreciated.  This is helpful. I am generally OK with content types.  My real issue is understanding if specific template layouts may be chosen from the layouts list when creating a web part page.  Example: Site Actions > More Options > Page > Web Part Page.  You get to choose a layout template such as Full Page, Vertical.  Can I make a layout template that appears in this list?

Comment: Publishing layouts are different from WIKI pages that are being used on team sites.

Comment: So, in this instance are Web Part pages tantamount to Wiki pages?

Answer (score 0):

here is some microsoft link that can help you the differences. Hope it helps

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-to-content-types-and-content-type-publishing-HA101631493.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the article.  It does a good job of explaining content types.  I do understand that distinction. I should have been more clear on my original question: I need help with creating a layout template for Web Part pages.  I want to be able to click on more options > web part page, I want to be able to choose a template other than those out of the box from the list provided for layouts.  I can see these options when I choose Publishing page.  Thanks for the help.